# WPF navigation services goBack not working

Tags: wpf, vb.net, navigationservice

I have a navigationWindow and some pages. The application startupURI is set to 'page1.xaml' .

If I show the NavigatoinUI, the forward and back buttons work perfectly, however if I call navigationserivce.goBack() I get an exception "Cannot navigate because there is no entry in the Back stack of the journal."

The code that navigates to page2

```
NavigationService.Navigate(New page2)
```

the code that doesn't work (in page2)

```
NavigationService.GoBack()
```

Any ideas? I've tried various ways of calling the navigationService methods.

cheers,

Comment: actually on my PC it works. Where did you put NavigationService.GoBack()?

Comment: it's in a leftButtonDown event of a grid (I'm using a grid as a button, inside another grid).

Comment: ok then the problem could be related with the Grid Background not set. Set it to Transparent for example.